# Draw a specified set on a complex plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Draw specified set on a complex plane:
$arg\left(  \frac{i}{z} \right) =  \frac{3 \pi }{4}, \left|  \frac{\overline{z}}{(1+i)^{11}} \right| > 1$

From the first condition I calculated $\varphi =  \frac{7 \pi }{4}$, and I also calculated the denominator from the second $-32+32i$ but I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

The second condition is equivalent to
$$|z|= |\bar z| >\bigl|(1+i)^{11}\bigr|=|1+i|^{11}=2^{\tfrac{11}2}=32\sqrt 2.$$

Answer (score 0):

let $$z=a+bi$$ then we have $$\left|(a-bi)\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{64}-\frac{i}{64}\right)\right|>1$$